# Крашится программа после использования FileDialog в QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Пишу прогу в QT на с++ с использованием QML. Добавил в QML возможность выбора папок (FileDialog). После открытия окна FileDialog крашится программа. Выяснил, что прога ломается в месте удаления объекта delete ptc в коде c++. Интересно то, что если FileDialog не использовать, то все работает так как надо. Странно.

Запускаю QML внутри объекта GUI:

```
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("GUI", this);
QQmlComponent *component = new QQmlComponent(&engine,QUrl("ui.qml"));
mainview = component->create();
```

Создание FileDialog внутри ui.qml в ApplicationWindow:

```
FileDialog {
    id: fileDialog
    property int number
    title: "Выбор дирректории"
    folder: shortcuts.home
    modality : Qt.WindowModal
    onAccepted: {
        switch (number) {
        case 0: secondPage.setDir(fileUrl.toString().replace("file:///", "")); break;
        case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4: case 5: case 6:
            firstPage.setDir(fileUrl,number); break;
        default: break;
        }
    }
}
```

Место краша проги:

```
bool raschet::R1()
{
    float PolPr = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        QList<float>* ptcA1;
        QString put = getData(1,0,0,0,(i/2 +2 ) % 3,i%2);
        if (!put.count())
            return false;
        while (!FormatPTC(&ptcA1, put, i % 2, (i/2 +2 ) % 3, 0, 0, -10, 10, 0.01))
            zapuskRasch(1, 20, 20, -10, -10, 0.01, 1, 0, 0, put, puts1);
        for (int j = 1; j <=3; j++)
        {
            poiskProval(ptcA1[0],ptcA1[j],&(PolPr = 0));
            //saveXLS(j-1,i+6,PolPr*60,sheet);
        }
        delete ptcA1; //!!!!!
    }
    return true; 
}
```

P.S. не выделяю память для ptcA1, т.к. она выделяется внутри функции FormatPTC

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Не очень понял во-первых, зачем ptcA1 создается как указатель и где под него выделяется память. У меня подозрение, что проблема именно в этом, а диалог просто заставляет ее проявляться. Попробуйте заменить на создание объекта.

Comment: Заменил создание переменной на QList<float>*  ptcA1 = new QList<float>.  Ничего не поменялось.
В данном случае я использую QList<float>*  ptcA1 чтобы работать с массивом списков, количество элементов которого я не знаю изначально. 
Память я выделяю в функции FormatPTC(QList<float> **ptcA, ... ):
    QList<float>* mas = new QList<float>[7] (семерка условно стоит);
    и возвращаю *ptcA = mas в конце выполнения функции

Comment: Падение программы при удалении указателя может говорить о том, что где-то ошибка в использовании самого указателя - выход за пределы, к примеру. Если указатель на список делается для реализации двухмерного динамического массива, то возможно лучше использовать `QList <QList <double> >` либо просто `double **` в зависимости от того, может ли быть разная размерность в разных элементах по одному измерению

Comment: Спасибо большое за совет! Это меня навело на мысль, что каждому new должно соответствовать delete. Соответственно, если я создаю массив QList<float>* ptcA1, то нужно удалять каждый его элемент  QList<float> с помощью delete[] ptcA1;
Все заработало ! Спасибо еще раз

Comment: Хм, я как-то упустил из виду, что ptcA1 это массив, и удаление надо делать с помощью `delete []`, а не просто `delete`

Comment: Хоть внутреннее представление QList и является массивом, QList<float>* ptcA1 это указатель, а не указатель на массив объектов и удаляться должен оператором delete, а не delete[]. Далее, в функцию FormatPTC первым параметром вы передаете указатель на указатель, то есть QList<float>**, зачем? Создайте QList<float> и передавайте указатель в функцию или ссылку;